# Should we use singleton pattern for connection creation or not?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, singleton

I’ve seen some people says it is OK to use singleton pattern to the Data Access Layer to create Connections. Others says we should not use singleton pattern. The arguments given by both parties are valid for some extend, but from software engineering point of view what is correct. For an example for a Web Application should we use singleton pattern to the Data Access Layer.

Thanks.

Comment: this question is for Java or C#?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this would apply for both languages

Answer (score 2):

1) Use connection pooling api's provided by Framework like Hibernate or server like Tomcat. By using them you are already having best practices in your app.

2) If you want to create custom connection provider class. Better make it un-instantiable by making constructors as private. No getInstance method. Only provide static helper methods which accepts connection config. parameters like URL,userName,pass and return java.sql.DataSource or java.sql.Connection object.